# Using variables in JQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a simple question about accessing variables in jQuery. Is there are way to access the variable (wrap) when I call the read function on click of 'a'.

```
(function() {
    var Example= {
        init: function() {
            var wrap = 'hello world';
            $('a').on('click', this.read);
        },

        read: function() {
            console.log(wrap)
        }
    };

    Example.init();
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to accomplish this.  Perhaps the easiest is to change the scope of the 'wrap' variable.  Currently, since it's declared with a var inside the `init` function, it's scoped to the `init` function and not available outside of `init` directly.  So, you can declare the 'wrap' outside the `init` (it could be a property of the 'Example' object):

```
    var Example= {
        wrap: 'hello world',
        init: function() {
            var self = this;
            $('a').click(function(){
                self.read();
            });
        },

        read: function() {
            console.log(this.wrap);
        }
    };

    ​Exa​mple.init();
```

This makes 'wrap' scoped to 'Example' and available as a property of 'Example' throughout any function defined within 'Example'.

(Edit: had to tweak this a bit to properly handle the closure.)

Comment: Is there any best practice for managing more variables with this sort of structure or would you just add more like the wrap: 'hello world'?

Comment: It depends on the project, really.  My objects tend to carry properties and functions that are what seem to me to be a natural part of the object.  In you're case, it's tough for me to tell if 'wrap' is a variable that should be a property of the 'Example' object or not.  For instance, if 'wrap' needed to 'do' anything else (such as hide or show itself) then I'd probably make wrap it's own object and let 'Example' (or any other objects you may have) execute calls directly on it.  If, however, 'wrap' is just a string that 'Example' uses, I'd leave it as a property of 'Example'.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to read up on code structure as I'm new to jQuery.

Comment: Just FYI - this structure isn't really a jQuery thing as much as a JavaScript thing.  Here are a couple of handy resources that I've used to get up to speed on JavaScript objects: 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/oopjs.shtml

Answer (score 3):

```
(function() {
    var wrap;
    var Example= {
        init: function() {
            wrap = 'hello world';
            $('a').on('click', this.read);
    ...
```

Because functions have access to all variables visible from their definition scope.

Comment: Thanks, would I also declare variables like this if I needed many for my project?

Comment: Yup, you can use as many as you want. If you have a number of related variables (imageWidth, imageHeight, imageName, for example), then it's a good idea to pass them as properties of an object: image.width, image.height etc..

Comment: So I could create:

var cache = {
var one = one
var two = two }

Won't this cause the same problem as before?!

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {
    var Example= {
        init: function() {
            this.wrap = 'hello world';
            $('a').on('click', this.read);
        },
        read: function() {
            console.log(this.wrap)
        }
    };
    Example.init();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: (Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jRJFQ/3/)

```
(function(){
    var Example= {
        wrap:null,
         init: function() {
            this.wrap = 'hello world';
            $('a').on('click', this.read);
         },

        read: function() {
            console.log(Example.wrap)
        }
    };
    Example.init();
}​)();​
```

Answer (score 0):

If you consider using the revealing module pattern you can define which variables are private and which are public like this:

```
var Example = (function(){

    var wrap = 'hello world',
        init = function(){
            ...
        },
        read = function(){
            ... // You can use `wrap` here
        };

    return { // Return public variables and methods
        init: init,
        read: read
    };

})();

Example.init();
```

Answer (score -1):

yup this should do it:

```
(function() {
    var wrap;
    var Example= {
        init: function() {
            var wrap = 'hello world';
            $('a').on('click', this.read);
        },

        read: function() {
            console.log(wrap)
        }
    };

    Example.init();
})();
```